# A set is the union of 0 and a union of [1/(2n+1),1/2n] n from 1 to infinity, is it a sequentially compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I couldn't find a counterexample, but I have no idea where to start the proof. Any suggestions on it?

sorry, I mistyped [] to ()

[The set looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFWCY.png)

Comment: if there are infinite many n, would that be a closed subset of R

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The set is closed (contains all its limit points ), and bounded. ..  hence compact, hence sequentially compact (we are in a metric space )...

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it, it should be [1/(2n+1),1/2n]

Comment: @bof you mean $(0,\frac 12) $?  I don't see it (yet )...

Comment: @ChrisCuster The question has since been edited, but originally the set was a union of **open** intervals plus the point $0.$

Comment: @bof I see your point then.  I was thinking ordered pairs...